# $\sup\{u_n\}$ and $\inf\{u_n\}$ where $u_n=(-1)^n+\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$ and $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

> Find $\sup\{u_n\}$ and $\inf\{u_n\}$, where
>   
> 1) $u_n=(-1)^n+\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$
>   
> 2) $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$

**My answer:**

1. Let $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

   Then, $\{x_n\}=\{-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1...\}$

   and $\{y_n\}=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},-1,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},...\}$.

   $\therefore$ range of $\{u_n\}=\{(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}),1,(-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}),0\}$

   $\Rightarrow\sup\{u_n\}=1$ and $\inf\{u_n\}=(-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$
2. Similarly, we find range of $\{u_n\}=\{(-1+1),(\frac{1}{2}+0),(\frac{-1}{3}-1),(\frac{1}{4}+0),(\frac{-1}{5}+1)...\}$.

   Define sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\},\{c_n\}\backepsilon$

   $\{a_n\}=\{(-1+1),(-\frac{1}{5}+1),(-\frac{1}{9}+1),...\}\in[0,1)\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sup\{a_n\}=1$

   $\{b_n\}=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6},...\}\in(0,\frac{1}{2}]\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

   $\{a_n\}=\{(-1-\frac{1}{3}),(-1-\frac{1}{7}),...\}\in[-1-\frac{1}{3},-1)\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\inf\{c_n\}=-1-\frac{1}{3}$

   $\therefore\sup\{u_n\}=1$ and $\inf\{u_n\}=-1-\frac{1}{3}$

> **Questions:** Is there an alternative method which doesn't rely totally on finding the range to get $\sup,\inf$ for such sequences?
>   
> Also, what can be said about the convergence of these sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as $$ -1 \leq \cos \frac{n \pi}{4} \leq 1, $$
and as 
$$ -1 \leq (-1)^n \leq 1, $$
so we must have
$$ -2 = -1 + (-1) \leq (-1)^n + \cos \frac{n \pi}{4} \leq 1 + 1 = 2. $$

Thus the sequence $\left( u_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is indeed a bounded sequence, and we have the inequalities
$$ -2 \leq \inf \left\{ \ u_n \, \colon \, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} \leq \sup \left\{ \ u_n \, \colon \, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} \leq 2. $$

However, we note that the terms of this sequence corresponding to $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 8$, respectively, run as follows:
$$ 
\begin{matrix}
n   & = & 1                     & 2 & 3                     & 4 & 5                     & 6 & 7 & 8 & \ldots \\
u_n & = & -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 & -1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 & -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 2 & \cdots
\end{matrix}
 $$

And, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we find that
$$ u_{n+8} = (-1)^{n+8} + \cos \frac{(n+8) \pi }{4} = (-1)^n(-1)^8 + \cos \left( \frac{n \pi }{4} + 2\pi \right) = (-1)^n + \cos \frac{ n \pi}{4} = u_n.  $$

Therefore the set 
$$ \left\{ \ u_n \, \colon \, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} = \left\{ \ -1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  0, 1, 2 \  \right\}. $$

Hence 
$$ \inf \left\{ \ u_n \, \colon \, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} = -1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$
and 
$$ \sup \left\{ \ u_n \, \colon \, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} = 2.  $$

Hope this helps.

Can you now handle the other sequence similarly?